# Nav2 launch file does not show map

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz

I am currently trying to simulate my Turtlebot2 in Gazebo using [this repo](https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2/tree/humble-devel), but am running into the problem that whenever I launch `turtlebot2_nav2.launch.py`, the map is not shown; also, the localization is inactive. Furthermore, I have to run the nav2 launch file in connection with the slam launch file or otherwise no maps are received at all.

I've tried to run `ros2 run map_server map_server map.yaml` but it wasn't working.

The launch file looks like this (I have split the launch files in the repo into separate pieces, since I also ran into problems):

```
import os
from unicodedata import name

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from nav2_common.launch import ReplaceString, RewrittenYaml
from launch.actions import TimerAction
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')
    slam = LaunchConfiguration('slam')
    map_dir = LaunchConfiguration(
        'map',
        default=os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('turtlebot2_gazebo'),
            'maps',
            'map_cafe_23Feb.yaml'))
    param_dir = LaunchConfiguration(
        'params_file',
        default=os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('turtlebot2_gazebo'),
            'config',
            'nav2_params.yaml'))
    #python_commander_dir = get_package_share_directory('nav2_simple_commander')
    
    rviz_config_file = os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory('turtlebot2_gazebo'), 'rviz', 'nav2.rviz')
        
    #rviz_config_file = LaunchConfiguration('rviz_config')
    #composition_config = LaunchConfiguration('composition', default=False)
    
    nav2_launch_file_dir = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('nav2_bringup'), 'launch')

    #turtlebot2_gazebo_dir = get_package_share_directory('turtlebot2_gazebo')
    
    turtlebot2_world_launch = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(
        'turtlebot2_gazebo'), 'launch', 'turtlebot2_world.launch.py')

    #namespaced_params = ReplaceString(
    #    source_file=param_dir, replacements={"/namespace": ("/", namespace)}
    #)

    #namespaced_rviz_config_file = ReplaceString(
    #    source_file=rviz_config_file, replacements={"/tb2": ("/", namespace)})
    turtlebot2_gazebo_package = FindPackageShare(
        package="turtlebot2_gazebo").find("turtlebot2_gazebo")


    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
           'map',
            default_value=map_dir,
            description='Full path to map file to load'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'params_file',
            default_value=param_dir,
            description='Full path to param file to load'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),
        
         DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'slam', default_value='True', 
        description='Whether run a SLAM'
    ),

        #IncludeLaunchDescription(
        #    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([turtlebot2_world_launch]),
        #    launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}.items()
        #),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                [nav2_launch_file_dir, '/bringup_launch.py']),
            launch_arguments={
                'map': map_dir,
                'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                'slam': slam,
                'params_file': param_dir}.items(),
        ),
        #IncludeLaunchDescription(
        #PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        #    os.path.join(turtlebot2_gazebo_package, "launch",
        #                 "turtlebot2_spawn_robot.launch.py")
        #),
        #launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}.items()
    #),

        Node(
            package='rviz2',
            executable='rviz2',
            arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file],
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
        ),
        
    ])
```

The `nav2_params.yaml` file looks like this:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: /scan
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    odom_topic: odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    navigators: ["navigate_to_pose", "navigate_through_poses"]
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0

    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25

    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.1
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: /scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: /scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.1
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins:
        ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: /scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: /scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "/home/jetracer/fiver_ws/src/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2/turtlebot2_gazebo/maps/map_cafe_23Feb.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: True
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 2000
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200



smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True


velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

    collision_monitor:
  ros__parameters:
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    cmd_vel_in_topic: "cmd_vel_smoothed"
    cmd_vel_out_topic: "cmd_vel"
    state_topic: "collision_monitor_state"
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    source_timeout: 1.0
    base_shift_correction: True
    stop_pub_timeout: 2.0
    # Polygons represent zone around the robot for "stop", "slowdown" and "limit" action types,
    # and robot footprint for "approach" action type.
    polygons: ["FootprintApproach"]
    FootprintApproach:
      type: "polygon"
      action_type: "approach"
      footprint_topic: "/local_costmap/published_footprint"
      time_before_collision: 1.2
      simulation_time_step: 0.1
      min_points: 6
      visualize: False
      enabled: True
    observation_sources: ["scan"]
    scan:
      type: "scan"
      topic: "scan"
      min_height: 0.15
      max_height: 2.0
      enabled: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2
```

And here is a picture of Rviz2 when the nav2_launch as well as all the other launches:

[image]